# Create a json from a List of list Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a list of lists that I want to convert to json, the list looks like:

```
[Country, Food, Detail, Population, Region, Extension]
[Germany, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[England, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[USA, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
[China, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
[Italy, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]
[France, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
```

I want to create a json like this

```
  "Germany"{
        "Food": 
         {
           "value": 1
         },
        "Detail":
         {
           "value": 2
         },
        "Population": 
         {
           "value": 3
         },
        "Region": 
         {
          "value": 4
         },
        "Extension": 
         {
          "value": 5
         }
    }
 "Italy"{
        "Food": 
         {
           "value": 10
         },
        "Detail":
         {
           "value": 11
         },
        "Population": 
         {
           "value": 12
         },
        "Region": 
         {
          "value": 13
         },
        "Extension": 
         {
          "value": 14
         }
    }...
```

I was trying with gson but I have can not created it, I have a problem when I add the other json into the last json. I get a result like this:

```
   "Germany"{
            "Food": 
            {
             "value": 1
            }
            ...} 
   "Germany"{
            "Food": 
            {
            "value": 10
            }
            "Detail": 
            {
            "value": 11
            }
        ...}
    "Italy"{
            "Food": 
            {
            "value": 10
            }
           "Detail": {
           "value": 11
            }
           ...}
```

This is the part of my code where I create the json

```
    JsonObject main2=  new JsonObject();
    JsonObject main =  new JsonObject();

  for (int row = 1; row < table.size(); row++) {
        for (int colum = 1; colum < table.get(0).size(); colum++) {
            JsonObject jsObj = new JsonObject();
            jsObj.add("value", new JsonParser().parse(table.get(row).get(colum)));
            main.add(table.get(0).get(colum), jsObj);
        }
        main2.add(table.get(row).get(0),main);
        gson.toJson(main2, writer);

    }
```

I am not sure what are I doing wrong, If I write the "main" the result is correct but when I write the "main2" I have that problem. There are other option because I tried in deferents ways buy I don have a correct result :(

Comment: The input format does not really match the semantics. I would recommend to change the input format if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of inner for loop, it should be  **main2** instead of **main**.